# jhipster update --force on existing project

Tags: jhipster

i use brew to install jhipster and the current version is 4.14.4 . and i have generated a 4.14.3 version project.how can i update the existing project to 4.14.4 and contain the code that i generated on 4.14.3 . here is the detail:

```
brew info jhipster
jhipster: stable 4.14.4 (bottled)
Generate, develop and deploy Spring Boot + Angular applications
https://jhipster.github.io/
/usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.1 (9,066 files, 31.7MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-03-25 at 10:49:51
/usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.3 (9,076 files, 31.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-04-18 at 22:01:45
/usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.4 (9,075 files, 31.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-05-17 at 23:04:12
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jhipster.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: node ✔, yarn ✔
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.8 ✔
```

and the .yo-rc.json file is :

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.sgcc.syn",
      "nativeLanguage": "zh-cn"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.3",
    "baseName": "pmt",
    "packageName": "com.sgcc.syn",
    "packageFolder": "com/sgcc/syn",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": "kafka",
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "4166646bfabd18ccec24a2d10d5b15229ba3fae4",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "zh-cn",
    "languages": [
      "zh-cn"
    ]
  }
}
```

i changed the     "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.3" to 4.14.4 and update the project :

```
jhipster upgrade
Using JHipster version installed globally
Executing jhipster:upgrade
Options:
Welcome to the JHipster Upgrade Sub-Generator
This will upgrade your current application codebase to the latest JHipster version
Looking for latest generator-jhipster version...
yarn info v1.6.0
4.14.4
Done in 0.29s.
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ERROR! No update available. Application has already been generated with latest version.
    at Environment.error (/usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.4/libexec/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
    at module.exports.error (/usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.4/libexec/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2064:18)
    at shelljs.exec (/usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.4/libexec/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/upgrade/index.js:163:30)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/jhipster/4.14.4/libexec/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/shelljs/src/exec.js:199:9
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:262:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:348:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
```

it seems that i should remove some directory,how can i resolve it

Comment: Why did you edit your  .yo-rc.json to change version and use --force? Just follow the doc https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock

jhipster
overrite package.json  //choose yes
the remainder conflict file i choose y or n on my demaind
```

as a result:

```
jhipster --version
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
4.14.4
```